# Is there a way to access properties inside the class mediator from outside the class mediator?

Tags: wso2, wso2-micro-integrator

I am trying to access the property named `logProperty` which is inside the class mediator outside of it. I need to log the value of the `logProperty` from that log mediator. But it prints null. Why is that? Isn't there a way to access class mediator properties globally?

```
<class name="com.example.LogMediator">
       <property name="logProperty" value="log"/>
</class>
<log level="full">
       <property expression="$ctx:logProperty" name="After Class Mediator"/>
</log>
```

This is my latest code,

> LogMediator

```
private String logProperty;

public boolean mediate(MessageContext context) {
     context.setProperty(logProperty, "result");
}

// getters and setters
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access it the way you are trying. As a workaround, you can set the value to the message context from within the class mediator.

```java
context.setProperty("logProperty",  logPropertyValue);
```

Another option is to pass the value to the Class mEdiator through a property.

```xml
<property value="log" name="logProperty"/>
<class name="com.example.LogMediator">
       <property name="logProperty" expression="$ctx:logProperty"/>
</class>
<log level="full">
       <property expression="$ctx:logProperty" name="After Class Mediator"/>
</log>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But unfortunately, it's not working. I used the XML code and also `context.setProperty("logProperty",  logPropertyValue);`. It is printing the value as `After Class Mediator = log`. Not the value I am setting through Class Mediator.

Comment: @SomeGuy can you elaborate on what you did exactly. Also can you share the relevant code.

Comment: I added the class mediator code and I used your XML code in my composite application to test it. What am I doing wrong here? Thank you.

Comment: @SomeGuy what do you get for `After Class Mediator`? Also I don't see a property name `private String logProperty;` assigned.  Change it to `context.setProperty("logProperty",  "Result");`

Comment: Isn't the getters and setters worked on it? Because I tested a few things and let's say I print it inside the class mediator like `log.info("logProperty: " + context.getProperty(logProperty));` it prints the value. And let's say there is a property inside XML code and the property name is `someVb` and if I do this `log.info("someVb: " + someVb);` it prints the value which is already set in the property value. I may be misunderstanding how these two work. Can you clarify this? Thank you.

Comment: @SomeGuy context.setProperty(NAME, VALUE)(https://github.com/wso2/wso2-synapse/blob/master/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/synapse/MessageContext.java#L181) accepts the property name and a value. So if your property name is `logProperty` you will have to set it like `context.setProperty("logProperty",  logProperty)`. The setter and getter will set the Class property to a variable.